# How do i fill the values of a column with the intercept and coefficient estimates using a nested for loop?

Tags: r, matrix, linear-regression, nested-loops

I am doing a sampling problem. I will sample the error term using 5 distinct values for the residual standard error and at each point, I generate a Y variable and then use the generated Y variable to run a regression. The X values to be used are already given. Let say the given values of X are

```
X = c(15,20,22,34,25)
```

To get the error, I will use the formula

```
error =rchisq(n = 1, df = 25)
```

Then to generate Y, I use this equation

```
Y = b0 + b1*X + error
```

with b0 = 0.525 and b1 = 1.2625

I then use the obtained Y and run a regression of Y on X and then save the intercept and slope obtained from this regression. So for each value for error obtained by sampling 5 times with different values of df (say 15,20,25,30, and 35), I will run the simulation 100 times to get the values for b0 and b1 which I want to save in a matrix with each column for each of the coefficients obtained by running the simulation 100 times using a given error gotten from each df.

This is what I did. I first created two matrices, each to hold the values for the intercept and slope separately as shown in the code below

```
dfs = seq(15,35,5)

dat = rep(NA,nsample*length(dfs))
beta0_sim  = matrix(data=dat, nrow=nsample, ncol=length(dfs))
beta1_sim  = matrix(data=dat, nrow=nsample, ncol=length(dfs))
```

Then I wrote this code to obtain each error term (the Sig2 in the code snippet), then run the regression 100 times (n.sim = number of simulations  = 100) for each error and save the result in the matrices as shown below

```
for (i in dfs){
  sig2 <- rchisq(n = 1, df = i)
  for (j in 1:n.sim){
    error <- rnorm(n = 1,mean = 0,sd = sqrt(sig2))
    Y = beta0 + beta1*X + error
    model <- lm(Y ~ X)
    beta0_sim[j,i] <- model$coefficients[1]
    beta1_sim[j,i] <- model$coefficients[2]
  }
}
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, j, i, value = model$coefficients[1]) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

What might be the issue? Note, I can do this manually for each df in which case I will have 5 results for each coefficient but this is tedious and I know there is a way to do this easily with a nested for loop where the number of matrices needed will be 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `i in dfs` means that `i` will take values `[1] 15 20 25 30 35`, and therefore `beta0_sim[j,i] <- model$coefficients[1]` will attempt to fill the matrix in positions `(1,15)`, etc, as opposed to `(1,1)` etc.

What you can do is add a variable `counter` to determine the index:

```r
counter = 1
for (i in dfs){
  sig2 <- rchisq(n = 1, df = i)
  for (j in 1:n.sim){
    error <- rnorm(n = 1,mean = 0,sd = sqrt(sig2))
    Y = beta0 + beta1*X + error
    model <- lm(Y ~ X)
    beta0_sim[j,counter] <- model$coefficients[1]
    beta1_sim[j,counter] <- model$coefficients[2]
  }
  counter = counter + 1
}
```